# Constructor dependency injection laravel 5

Tags: php, constructor, dependency-injection, laravel-5

I've upgraded my laravel app from 4.2 to 5, and I'm getting the following error when trying to inject my dependency:

```
<?php namespace App\Classes\Api\Zurmo;

  use App\Classes\Api\Rest\ApiRestHelper;

  class Connector implements ConnectorInterface {

  public function __construct(ApiRestHelper $rest)
  {
     ...
```

**Argument 1 passed to App\Classes\Api\Zurmo\Connector::__construct() must be an Instance of App\Classes\Api\Rest\ApiRestHelper, none given**

As far as I can see, its looking ok, what am I missing here?

Comment: How do you use this class?

Comment: the Connector class above is called from a controller like so:
use App\Classes\Api\Zurmo\Connector as Zurmo;

Comment: Did you bind your interface to your class-implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want Laravel to resolve your dependencies automatically you have to instanciate the class through the [Service Container](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/container):

```
$zurmo = App::make('App\Classes\Api\Zurmo\Connector');
```

Or with the `app()` function:

```
$zurmo = app('App\Classes\Api\Zurmo\Connector');
```

***Note*** that you have to write out the full path of the class

---

Alternatively you could let Laravel inject the connector itself in the controller. For example:

```
use App\Classes\Api\Zurmo\Connector as Zurmo;

// ...

public function __construct(Zurmo $zurmo){
    $this->zurmo = $zurmo;
}

public function someAction(){
    $this->zurmo->doMagic();
}
```